# Oracle Apex 19 - Dynamic Actions - How can I set a Date Picker application item with sysdate by default by change action?

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex 19.2 I'm using dynamic actions on an item STATE that needs a the DATE Date Picker value set to sysdate only when STATE=2.

How can I set an application item with sysdate in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy' by default by the change action?

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting a CHANGE dynamic action on the item STATE with both Set Value and Clear action.
Setting value with a PL/SQL function body like this

```
return to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Affected item is DATE.
Escape Special Caracters avoids slash errors at runtime.